# iMac frequently loses connection to peripherals

Tags: keyboard, usb, monterey

Ever since I upgraded to Monterey, my iMac is acting weird. Frequently (like, a few times a week), it will be working great and then suddenly I see a notification that one (or sometimes all) of my external drives has been disconnected without unmounting. And at the same time, my USB keyboard and trackball will stop working. I've recently started leaving another USB mouse and Bluetooth keyboard connected, and when this happens they stop working as well, even though they were working fine before. Swapping USB devices to different USB ports doesn't help, neither does turning off the Bluetooth keyboard or power cycling the USB external hub. The only thing that works is I can ssh in from another computer and `sudo reboot` it.

**Update** Did I saw "a few times a week"? It's happened 3 times this evening. I'm going to try upgrading the firmware on my CalDigit TS3 Plus if it stays up long enough to do so.

Comment: The symptoms you’re describing are those of a USB reset. Many possible causes. Let’s narrow them down. Start by running without your hub attached and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Monterey has USB issues. Wait for an update https://www.macrumors.com/2021/10/29/monterey-usb-hub-issues-reported/